# React Invariant Violation: Minified React error #267

Tags: ios, reactjs, cordova

[image: Invariant Violation]

Get this message from a ReactDOM.render exception.

I am running React in a cordova application on iOS.  It happens infrequently, usually when running the app the first time after some time of device sleep or a reinstall.

Any ideas?!

top level render method here

```
function renderReact() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <App>
      <AppRoute />
    </App>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  );
}
```

App component:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <WrapperDiv>
          {this.props.children}
          <ModalController />
          <DialogController />
        </WrapperDiv>
        {/* {__DEVTOOLS__ && <DevTools />} */}

      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Share the `render` code where this problem seems to appear.

Comment: Hey @Fawaz there are quite a lot of components rendered!  Base render method added...

Comment: seems to have happened since upgrading react from 15.x -> 16.3.2, and using React Fragments...(other changes too, so not 100% sure if this is the cause)

Comment: App should be inside Provider. So make provider the top most component. This is not a solution, but you should try.

Comment: To solve this problem, you need to find the problem first. For that make a development build and run it to identify the error stacktrace.

Comment: yeah, thats the main problem - I can't reproduce it on a dev build!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sent a dev build to our beta testers and one managed to reproduce it.

Seems that this specific issue is due to React.cloneElement being called with a null parameter.